# How to connect multiple client to server

Tags: c#

I have two application one is Client and other is sever , how client application automatically detect the sever application if sever application is running

please tell me best method for this

Comment: Is this a programming question, or do you already have the server/client applications?

Comment: What do you mean, please expand your thoughts

Comment: Why not just have the client attempt to connect to the server?

Comment: StackOverflow is a website targeted at **professional software developers**.  If you are not sure about what StackOverflow is or how to behave here, please review the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  Your question was closed because it is low quality and unanswerable in any reasonable manner.  If you wish to get good answers, you **must** ask good questions.  Low quality questions like this one are not accepted here.  I would **strongly** suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/) for hints on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the IP of the server, then try and connect, if its just "running somewhere" on your local network you could send a broadcast

An example: (not my code, borrowed)

```
  public static void Main()
  {
   Advertise server = new Advertise();
  }
  public Advertise()
  {
   Thread advert = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sendPackets));
   advert.IsBackground = true;
   advert.Start();
   Console.Write("Press Enter to stop");
   string data = Console.ReadLine();
  }
  void sendPackets()
  {
   Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
           SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
   sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
              SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1);
   IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 9050);
   string hostname = Dns.GetHostName();
   byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hostname);
   while (true)
   {
     sock.SendTo(data, iep);
     Thread.Sleep(60000);
   }
  }
```

The client then listens for the broadcast, if it receives 1 or more responses it could offer the user a what do you want to connect to.

This of course only works on a local network (with no firewalls/subnets)

Otherwise, you have to ask the user where the server is

Comment: ok! how a client listen this request

Comment: As your questions been closed, please google for broadcast and there are a number of examples

Answer (score 0):

Yours application tries to connect to the server.
The server replies.
The server is running.

Yours application tries to connect to the server.
The server does not reply.
The server is not running or there is some other problem.